# how to show thumbnail of friends by using usercontrol in asp.net.

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am working on my project and am not able to show thumbnail in 3*3 order.I have used one User control (image,URL).so its will look just like friends in my list and when i will click on any one friend the profile of that particular friend should be displayed.

Comment: There should be a image control which you can resize it to 3x3 size and display over the forms right?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider using ASP.NET ListView as described in [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/10/the-asp-listview-control-part-1-building-a-product-listing-page-with-clean-css-ui.aspx), so you build a landing page of your friends details.